# How Appium Page factory will pick correct xpath when both Android & IOS Xpaths are defined

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I am new to Appium and planned to use Appium page factory to execute my test with same script in both android and IOS, Currently i am working on Android device so i am keeping IOS xpath as null, When i execute my script its throwing the error "userNameTextBox=null" . I have two questions here 
1. Based on what criteria Appium page factory will know which xpath to select android or IOS
2. Why in my code its throwing "userNameTextBox as Null" although i am using Android driver.

```
 private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    @AndroidFindBy(className = "android.widget.EditText")
    @iOSBy(className = "")
    private AndroidElement userNameTextBox;


  public void login(String userName, String password) throws InterruptedException {
        userNameTextBox.sendKeys(userName);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, InterruptedException {
        LaunchApplication.launchApp("samsungtablet");--This code will launch the app based on device passed
        LoginPage lp= new LoginPage();


        lp.login("test", "test");---Failing here 

}
```

Comment: show code that initializes and/or passes in reference to the driver...

Comment: Thanks for your tip, That was the issue, I fixed and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Previously the application was not setting the driver instance correctly as a result i was getting xpath value as null, I added below function to call driver from the launchapplication class and it worked with that.

```
public void login(String userName, String password) throws InterruptedException {
 this.driver = LaunchApplication.driver;
         PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);

        userNameTextBox.sendKeys(userName);
}
```